# PHP preg_replace: limit replacements

Tags: php, replace

Im using this piece of code:

```
<?php $newstring = preg_replace("/[\n\r]/", "<br />" , $googlemapsbox_text); echo $newstring; ?>
```

To replace the \n's. What I would like to achieve: limit the amount of `<br />` per line, so when preg_replace finds more than 1 \n per line, they ALL should be replaced with ONE `<br />`.

I hope my question is clear to you, sorry for the weird English

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
preg_replace("/[\n\r]+/", "<br />", // rest of your code
=====================^ add a + there on your regex
```

Comment: I did! Thanks a lot for the swift and correct answer! Will accept asap.